# Jasmine: test that image exists in the folder

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angularJS project which is tested with Jasmine.
I need to write a unit test which will check that the image exists in the folder and was not deleted. In my case that's just a default profile picture, for example.

The idea is that we download image and send success on load or not success on error. If I try it in plain JS - everything works like a charm. But somehow it always fails with Jasmine. What's wrong? And is there any better way to test that the image exists and loads correctly?

Sorry for Coffeescript instead of JS. But it still should be easy to follow:

```
describe "Default services: ", ->

    beforeEach angular.mock.module("default.services")

    describe "App Image: ", ->

        async = new AsyncSpec(this)
        success = false

        async.beforeEach (done) ->
            inject (defaultStuff) ->
                img = new Image()

                img.onload = ->
                    success = true
                    done()
                img.onerror = ->
                    success = false
                    done()

                img.src = defaultStuff.appImage

        it "should have default app image", inject (defaultStuff) ->
          expect(defaultStuff.appImage).not.toBe(null)

        async.it "should download default app image (e. g. check that it exists)", (done) ->
            expect(success).toBe(true)
```